# Short exact sequence and splitting lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Given a (short exact) sequence of abelian groups. Are the following true?

Case 1: $0\to A\to B\to B/A\to 0$ is exact and splits for all $A\leq B$.

Case 2: If $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact and B is free abelian then the sequence it splits.

Case 3,4: Similar as in 2, but saying $A,C$ are free abelian respectively.

The original question was: a short exact sequence $0\to A\to\mathbb{Z}^8\to\mathbb{Z}\to0$ implies $A\cong\mathbb{Z}^7$?

Comment: What progress have you made on this problem? Please update your post with this information.

Comment: Sorry, a typo...

Answer (score 1):

Assertions in cases 1 2 and 3  are false. Counter-example for all:
$$0\to n\mathbf Z\to\mathbf Z\to \mathbf Z/n \mathbf Z\to 0 $$
doesn't split since $ \mathbf Z/n \mathbf Z$ has torsion and a direct summand of  $ \mathbf Z$ doesn't.

On the contrary, if $C$ is free, the exact sequence splits, since it's enough to take as  images of the elements in a basis of $C$ any element in their inverse images.

Comment: Case 1, $0\to A\to B\to B/A\to 0$ is always eaxct (of course $A$ is subgroup of $B$ and both abelian).
Thx, what you said helps me.